# Need to install mysql-devel in the server that has cPanel - `libmysqlclient_16' not found

Tags: php, python, mysql, cpanel

I have a Python script in cPanel and need to connect my script to MYSQL, for connecting Python to MYSQL I need to have libmysqlclient

When I run my code, the system shows me the following error

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/init.py", line 19, in <module>
import _mysql
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18: version `libmysqlclient_16' not found (required by /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

- server-os: Centos 6.9
- cpanel-version: 68.0.13

list of `libmysqlclient` in `/usr/lib64`

```
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.15
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.18
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.18.1.0
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.a
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysql.connector`

On ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install python-mysql.connector` or `python3-mysql.connector` for python 3

Then:

```
import mysql.connector
mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='mysql',user='root',password='')
```